# How can you block the image to appear on WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a simple web browser using c# and I want to block the images to appear on WebBrowser control. Can you please show me a sample code for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove image-tags from the source htm like this:

```
string content = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"http://www.google.com/");
string contentWithoutImages = Regex.Replace(content, @"<img(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
webBrowser1.DocumentText = contentWithoutImages;
```

Comment: @Trond What about images without img tags? css sprites for example